# Do Powerbeats2 Use Bluetooth LE (4.0)?

Tags: headphones

Yesterday I bought Powerbeats2 wireless in-ear headphones at Best Buy. I am wondering if they use Bluetooth LE or older Bluetooth technology, such as Bluetooth 2.1.

[image]

I've looked on Apple's website and Beats' website, but neither of them provide specs for the headphones.

**Since Beats is an Apple subsidiary, I am assuming that this question is not off-topic.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is Bluetooth 4.0. I've been using it for the past one year. Although Beats or Apple website do not provide this information this Engadget [article](http://www.engadget.com/2014/06/12/powerbeats2-beats-by-dre/) explicitly mentions it.

> The Powerbeats² keep the (albeit modified) hook-over-the-ear design, but liberate heads from handsets via Bluetooth 4.0